# State-space representation of heat equation?

Tags: convex-optimization, heat-equation, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, linear-control

I have the heat equation :

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u\left(x,y,t\right)}{\partial t}=\alpha\nabla^2 u\left(x,y,t\right)+\beta I\left(x,y\right)
\label{eq:HE}
\end{equation}

as $u$ to be the temperature value at time $t$ correspond to the point $\left(x,y\right)$ and

\begin{equation}
\nonumber
\nabla^2 u\left(x,y,t\right):=\left(\frac{\partial^2 u\left(x,y,t\right)}{\partial x^2}\right)+
\left(\frac{\partial^2 u\left(x,y,t\right)}{\partial y^2}\right).
\label{eq:Nabla-2}
\end{equation}

In addition

\begin{equation}
\nonumber
\alpha:= \frac{\kappa}{c \rho}
\label{eq:alpha}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\nonumber
\beta:= \frac{1}{c \rho}
\label{eq:beta}
\end{equation}

with $\kappa$, $c$ and $\rho$ all in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ to be thermal conductivity, the specific heat capacity and the mass density, respectively. We let $x\in\left[-1,+1\right]$, $y\in\left[-1,+1\right]$, $t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and also $u\left(x,y,0\right)=0$.

Here, $I$ to simulate an external source of heat that is a Gaussian function$\colon$

\begin{equation}
 I\left(x,y\right) = I_0 \cdot \exp{ \left[-2 \left[ \left(\frac{x-x_c}{\omega}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-y_c}{\omega}\right)^2 \right] \right]}
 \label{eq:Heat}
\end{equation}

with an initial value

\begin{equation}
 I_0=  \frac{2\mathcal{P}}{\pi\omega^2}
 \label{eq:Heat-I}
\end{equation}

by knowing $\omega$ and $\mathcal{P}$ to be the radius of the Gaussian waist and the power of the heat power of the Gaussian distribution, respectively. We set $\mathcal{P}=10^6$ (Watt) and $\omega=3$ pixels while letting $\left(x_c,y_c\right)$ to take all possible trajectory points that the Gaussian distribution can move over.

$---$

My question is now, how the heat equation explained above along with its external source of heat can be rewritten in terms of a state-space model?

The final goal is to solve the state-space model of heat equation using linear quadratic regulator (LQR) approach.

Many thanks

Comment: With state space model do you mean discretizing space in order to get a finite dimensional state space model or do you still want to be able to solve for the analytical solution?

Comment: Secondly, you mentioned LQR, but your PDE doesn't have any inputs one can choose freely.

Comment: I believe, I need a finite discretized model. What I really need is to convert the PDE in to the form shown in 1st slide of this PDF file ---> https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-30-feedback-control-systems-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT16_30F10_lec18.pdf

Comment: The PDE starts from initial condition $t=0$. The problem is about a moving nozzle over a board that performs 3D printing. The external source of heat of the PDE is the laser nozzle. and $\left(x_c,y_c\right)$ are the points on the board where the nozzle uses as its trajectory. I need to find the trajectory points using LQR approach.

Comment: Section 2.4 of this paper --->   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272161706_A_State_Space_Representation_for_One-Dimensional_Microwave_Heating_Temperature_Model  is very near to what I really need.

Comment: Specifically, in section 2.4, my desire is to have the heat equation in form of the equations (31) and (32).